# Why cant I connect to 5GHz with my b/g/n WiFi Card?

Tags: wireless

I have a Realtek RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n on my Quantal amd64 system. I installed the kernel modules for that card and modprobe that module. I can only view to the 2.4GHz WLANs. The module Im talking about was downloaded from the realtek page.

[Here is some good info](http://pastebin.com/j7cvquw0). Well my configuration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Realtek RTL8188CE WLAN adapter is designed to connect to a [IEEE 802.11b/g/n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) communication protocol. This protocol is available for both the 2.4, and the 5.0 GHz frequency band. However according to the hardware specifications this adapter like many other *"802.11n"* adapters only supports the 2.4 GHz band:

> - Complete 802.11n solution for 2.4GHz band <sup>[Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=272)</sup>

To be able to connect to signals in the 5.0 GHz band you need to have an adapter supporting this. These usually are named as *"dual-band"* or similar.

Comment: To find out if the adapter supports 5GHz you can always [check with iwlist](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137894/3285).

Answer (score 4):

Not all N cards support 5GHz.  This one doesn't.

A clue is the fact that it is labelled with B and G but not A.  Of the standards older than N, B and G both used the 2.4GHz band while A used the 5GHz band.  N cards supporting both bands are often labeled as supporting A/B/G/N, whereas N cards supporting only 2.4GHz are often labeled as B/G/N.

The newer standard AC also uses the 5GHz band.  Only N supports both bands, with mandatory 2.4GHz support and optional 5GHz support.  So if a device supports AC and N that should mean it supports N on both bands.